# How far away is the barycentre?

Tags: geometry, triangles, plane-geometry, barycentric-coordinates

Suppose we have a triangle $abc$ and point $x$ on $bc$. I think the barycentre $B = (a+b+c)/3$ should be about $\|x-a\|/3$ distance away from $x$.

[image]

This is not true because measuring the blue segment says its about 3.5 times the length of the red segment.

Is there any constant $C>0$ such that $|xB| > C |xa|$ for all triangles?

This might be completely obvious but I'm just not seeing it right now.

Comment: Consider what happens when $|cb|\to 0$

Comment: But your final question has nothing to do with the barycentre.

Comment: Thanks. Corrected now.

Comment: As $|cb| \to 0$ it becomes a one-dimensional problem and $|xB| = |xa|/3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $|ac|=|bc|=1$, $\angle acb=\pi-\epsilon$ and $|cx|=\epsilon$. As $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$, you can easily show $C$ should go to $0$.

(you can prove it using $|xB|>C|xa|\Rightarrow 2\epsilon\ge|xc|+|Bc|\ge|xB|>C|xa|\ge C(|ca|-|cx|)=C(1-\epsilon)$)

Comment: What if we also demand all the angles are at most $\pi/2$?

Comment: @Daron - same for that case. fix $\angle acb$. take $|ca|\rightarrow 0$ and since the angle is acute, we can send $|Bx|\rightarrow 0$. Then you can make similar thing.